# Dual-boot automatic load Windows when resuming from Hibernate

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, hibernate

I have this setup: Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu (grub).
My bios boot options are:

1. Windows Bootloader:
2. Ubuntu boot option:

   - Windows 8.1
   - Ubuntu 14.04

When I select Windows Bootloader it goes straight to Windows.
When I select Ubuntu it goes to the Grub menu from where I can select Ubuntu or Windows.

My current default is the Ubuntu boot option.

Right now I can hibernate Windows, boot the computer and select Ubuntu. This way I can lose data if I forget I am hibernated in Windows and start Ubuntu and do something and then come back into Windows. (Lots of people have this happened to them).

My question:
How can I make this setup so that when I hibernate in Windows and then boot the computer, to go straight in Windows loading the hibernation file and not give me the option of dual boot menu? (while in the same time if there would be no hibernation file, to have the option to boot either of the OS)